# Character encoding issue related with currency symbols

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, encoding

I am creating a web application.I am using linux(fedora 16) for the development of the application and technology used is spring MVC.Its a maven project.When I run application in debug environment the application works fine and its displaying special characters properly.E.g.I want to display currency symbol pound(₤) its displaying properly. But if I deploy the application on tomcat 6.0.26 or 6.0.35 on windows machine then it is not displaying currency symbols properly.E.g.it show pound sign as "Â£".So can anyone having idea about this issue.

Comment: How are you displaying these values?

Comment: Please provide a bit more information about where you get the data from and how you display it.

Comment: I am storing UTF code of currency in database and displaing in html.

Comment: Please provide a code snipped from where you display these symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your tomcat server's catalina.sh (catalina.bat) add the args like this;

```
   set JAVA_OPTS=-Djavax.servlet.request.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

and also set **URIEncoding="UTF-8"** on your Connector tag in server.xml. see this;

```
   <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Comment: The `javax.servlet.request.encoding` system property does nothing. That string is only valid as a request attribute. Setting `file.encoding` also does nothing, since this question has nothing to do with files. Finally, setting the `URIEncoding` will only affect the interpretation of parameters sent as URL parameters (but is generally a good idea to set, since the whole world really ought to be using UTF-8 these days).

Comment: Remember to change ajp connector if your tomcat is behind an apache
`<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>`

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to use a [CharacterEncodingFilter](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q3). I recommend reading the entire FAQ that link points to.

Comment: CharacterEncodingFilter is needed for POST requests (e.g. org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter or org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter may be used)